# How to refresh the composite while filtering through text field?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have a section and `formtoolkit` in one composite. When I enter some text in Search box (`Text` field) it should filter based on user input and show the results below. I am facing one problem while filtering the data. How to refresh the data in composite when user enters text in Text field.

I want a solution which is same as how it works in

> Preferences -> compiler -> Errors/Warnings?

Example:

[image]

If I enter "null" in search box it will display all the related "null" values below.

How to achieve this implementation for filtering/refreshing the composite data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preference page you reference does this with a `Composite` containing all the controls to be filtered. The `Composite` uses the `GridLayout` layout.

Each control has a `GridData` layout data. To set a control visible or invisible it uses:

```
control.setVisible(visible);
((GridData)control.getLayoutData()).exclude = !visible;
```

Once this has been done it calls:

```
composite.layout(true, true);
```

to redo the layout of the `Composite` completely.

Most of this code is in `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.preference.OptionsConfigurationBlock`

To do the filtering you create a `Text` field for the filter and add a `ModifyListener` to listen to changes in the text.

Each time the text changes you match the text of each control with the filter and set the control visible / invisible as described above. At the end of filtering you do the `layout` call.

Comment: Thank you greg. but i want to know how to filter the data based on user input in Text field and refresh the composite at same time. Thanks.

Comment: Added an outline of how to do the actual filtering.